# Windows Application event logs stooped logging

Tags: windows, windows-server, event-log, event-viewer

I am encountered with an issue with the event viewer. The issue is that new application event logs are not logging in the file(archive). And if I try manually generate an error log in "application" it shows on the head like

**Application | Number of events: 8,633 (!) new events available.**

But after a refresh, there is no new log. I tried to find solution o the google but unfortunately, I can find any solution to it.

P.S.Logging enabled

P.S.S. Picture of issue:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a filter enabled?

Comment: No, the filter is standard. I tried to change some setting with filter, but issue the same.

Comment: Have you tried deleting all the old application logs?

Comment: No, because I need them. And There was only one file with logs. Only one, I mean that there was an archive file with all logs.

Comment: Well, I think there is a problem with archiving logs. Yesterday I change a maximum log size to 30,720 KB and it starts to write logs again to the same file. I will inform all of you if there will some changes in my issue. Thanks to all

Comment: Find the same problem : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2570117d-537f-490d-a373-e5a347d1ce45/event-logs-archive-log-when-full?forum=win10itprogeneral

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. 
The issue was in windows system. After the update, the issue resolved.

https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1566822895&rver=6.7.6640.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https:%2F%2Fsocial.technet.microsoft.com%2FForums%2Fwindows%2Fen-US%2F2570117d-537f-490d-a373-e5a347d1ce45%2Fevent-logs-archive-log-when-full%3Fforum%3Dwin10itprogeneral%26stoAI%3D10&id=254354